# Logic behind a checkers game?

Tags: java, logic

I'm starting to make a checkers game and I've got all my graphics + the board drawn. Before I moved on to creating the pieces I was wondering what an easy way to tackle the logic side of the movement of pieces.. Should I make a table of every square, detecting if it has a piece and if so, what color? (i.e 0=empty, 1=red, 2=black) or do you guys have a better idea to this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Learn to play checkers. 2. Write down on piece of paper checkers rules (don't copy them, write them by yourself). 3. Try to design how you could program it, and write it on a piece of paper as well. 4. Try to actually program it. 5. If you get a problem holding you for a day, ask here. Programming is about creating solutions, this site is not to create solutions for others but to help them when they fail.

Comment: The way you're asking this, you're just going to get a discussion. Can you elaborate more on what strategy you want to use, what you've tried already, what isn't working? Try drawing it out on paper or use a real checkers board and imagine how you would implement that in an object oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just have a two dimensional array of Space objects. Don't know how you're rendering each space, but the Space object could say if it's occupied by a piece, and if so, what is the color, etc.

Comment: that would be predifined, right? Or maybe I could write a for loop for that..

Comment: if you mean the board would be predefined, yeah i guess, just depends on what you want to do.  Like the comments are saying, there are many ways to skin a cat, just gotta choose the way you are comfortable with and go with it.

Comment: Hi @dardo. I edited out the "just my 2c" line - every answer here is just somoene's 2c. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a reversi game and I just used a table of values for each square and it worked fine assigning a number to each possible state. When you move a piece you would have a function that would check if a move is legal then erase where the piece from one square and put it in the next one. I'm sorry if I missed something applicable but I don't actually know how to play checkers.